# what is the name for this method of finding volume between a given surface and a plane

Tags: integration, volume

i want to know about the method used in the answer. 
how do they just do a triple interal over r dr dz d(theta).

could you tell me the name of his method, or link me to a youtube video.

[question and example answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMuQq.png)

Comment: do you mean the $r\,dr\,d\theta$?

Comment: It is a volume integral. I believe Khan Academy probably have good videos about it in the section about multivariable calculus

Comment: Google Jacobian of a transformation and solids of revolution

Comment: change of variables theorem

Comment: @pranavB23 I agree that the Jacobian is used to change variables, but this is not a solid of revolution

Comment: They're making a change of variables from Cartesian  to cylindrical coordinates. r appears as the Jacobian.

Comment: @JohnDoe if he is looking for problems of that kind solids of revolution are good to start volume integrals

Comment: thanks alot guys